# Understanding pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, operators, fopen

I'm reading through K&R C. In t he back there's some sample `fopen` code. I don't particularly understand one part.

```
#define OPEN_MAX 20

FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX] = {
    { 0, NULL, NULL, _READ, 0 },             // _READ = 01
    { 0, NULL, NULL, _WRITE, 1 },            // _WRITE = 02
    { 0, NULL, NULL, _WRITE | _UNBUF, 2 }    // _UNBUF = 04
};

FILE *fopen(char *name, char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp;

    for (fp = _iob; fp < _iob + OPEN_MAX; fp++)
    /* ... */
}
```

The statement `fp < _iob + OPEN_MAX` is what's tripping me up.

- `fp`: file pointer
- `_iob`: file array
- `OPEN_MAX`: integer

It seems to be *adding* a file array to an integer, then evaluating whether or not it's *larger than* a file pointer! How is the statement `fp < _iob + OPEN_MAX` possible?

Comment: It's possible due to pointer arithmetic being allowed in C. You can think of addresses (the values inside pointers) as integers that designate locations in memory. If two locations are adjacent, the difference between their addresses is a number.

Comment: When you use an array in an expression like that, it decays to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: That's very basic pointer arithmetics. It is explained in every C book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most contexts, when you use an array as an l-value, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array. So

```
fp < _iob + OPEN_MAX
```

is equivalent to:

```
fp < &(_iob[0]) + OPEN_MAX
```

And when you perform arithmetic on a pointer to an array element, it's equivalent to array indexing. So this is the same as:

```
fp < &(_iob[OPEN_MAX])
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The expression `_iob + OPEN_MAX` causes `_iob` to be treated as a pointer to its first element within this expression (this is called [array-to-pointer decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3425536)).
2. The resulting `FILE` pointer is then offset by `OPEN_MAX` (the `+`).
3. The `<` then compares the two resulting `FILE` pointers (pointers are just integers under the hood).